# Working on rails, i have text fields and text areas to receive text, but it shows the validation error "Topic cannot be empty"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

After typing in topic and details in the appropriate text field and area, it still shows "validation error" "Topic cannot be empty". what is the problem? I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
This is the task partial
_task.html.erb:

 <li id="task-<%= task.id %>">
      <%= link_to gravatar_for(task.user, size: 50), task.user %>
      <span class="task"><%= link_to task.user.name, task.user %></span>
      <span class="topiclabel">Title:</span>
      <span class="topic"style=color:black> <%= task.topic %></span>
      <span class="detailslabel">Details: </span>
      <span class="detail"><%= task.detail %></span> 
      <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(task.created_at) %> ago.
      </span>
</li> 

Schema:

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170526194708) do

  create_table "stages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "topic"
    t.datetime "duration"
    t.text     "detail"
    t.integer  "task_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["task_id"], name: "index_stages_on_task_id"
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_stages_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_stages_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "topic"
    t.integer  "member"
    t.text     "detail"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_tasks_on_user_id_and_created_at"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_tasks_on_user_id"
  end

routes.rb:

 resources :tasks,          only: [:create, :destroy]

task.rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :stages
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
   validates :user_id, presence: true
   validates :topic, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
   validates :detail, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }

end
```

Project_pages_controller.rb:

```
def home
    if logged_in?
      @task = current_user.tasks.build
end


_task_form.html.erb:

<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :topic, placeholder: "Compose new task..." %>
    <%= f.text_area :detail, placeholder: "Write task details..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>


This is the show page
```

show.html.erb

```
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <% if @user.tasks.any? %>
      <% if @user.stages.any? %>
      <h3>Tasks (<%= @user.tasks.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="tasks">
        <%= render @tasks %>
        <%= render @stages %>
      </ol>
      <%= will_paginate @tasks %>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

This is my controller;

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
    include TasksHelper
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.build(task_params)
    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = "Task created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'workshareapp_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:detail)
    end

end
```

Comment: where's your controller?

Comment: It seems the controller you posted is not complete. Where are the `update` and / or `create` methods? Where are you saving your object?

Comment: are you allowing the attributes properly using strong parameters?

Comment: Thanks Farhan, I have just added my controller.

Answer (score 0):

validates :topic, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
This clause validates the topic attribute in your record to be present and within 140 char length. This is used to validate record before save. You may remove it if you really dont need it here. Another option you can create a form model which is used specifically for this form.

Comment: Please can you explain to me how to do that and how I would link it to the form since its already attached to the task model?

Comment: I removed the validation, but when i submitted, it displayed on the page but the title was empty going back to the fact that it didn't see the texts in the text_field, can  it be a problem of using a text-field? The details was text-area and it displayed.

Comment: That didn't work, obviously its about picking up the text typed into the text area.

Comment: def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:detail, :topic)
end

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a validation in your model Task.

Comment: Do I have to remove the validation attached to the model task first?

Comment: I removed the validation, but when i submitted, it displayed on the page but the title was empty going back to the fact that it didn't see the texts in the text_field, can  it be a problem of using a text-field? The details was text-area and it displayed.

Comment: That didn't work, obviously its about picking up the text typed into the text area.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the :topic field in your permit, which is why it's not being processed.

```
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:detail, :topic)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Cristobal, figured that out yesterday after starting to look at it from the beginning.